# Call class' constructor by reflection with Kotlin

Tags: java, android, reflection, kotlin

I have the following data class

```
data class Person (val id: Int? = null, val name: String, val active: Boolean)
```

I need to call it's constructor by reflection. I tried the following code

```
private fun <T> createEntity(constructor: Constructor<*>, vararg args: T) : Any {
    return constructor.newInstance(args)
}
```

and call it with an array for the `args` parameter.

```
val fields = entity.declaredFields
var elements = Array<Any>(getFieldsCount(fields), { i ->
    val index = cursor.getColumnIndex(fields[i].name.toUpperCase())
    when (fields[i].type) {
        kotlin.Int::class.java -> cursor.getInt(index)
        kotlin.Boolean::class.java -> if (cursor.getInt(index) == 1) true else false
        else -> cursor.getString(index)
    }

})
val test = createEntity(entity.constructors.first(), *elements)
```

With `entity: Class<T>` and `cursor: Cursor` from a local database
Kotlin Documentation says :

> When we call a vararg-function, we can pass arguments one-by-one, e.g. asList(1, 2, 3), or, if we already have an array and want to pass its contents to the function, we use the spread operator (prefix the array with *)

but even with the `*` I keep getting the following exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong number of arguments; expected 3, got 1
```

Can anyone give me some tips on how to instantiate my class? Thanks

Comment: You have to use the spread operator here. How do you invoke `createEntity`?

Comment: I edited my question @Michael and as you can see, I use the spread operator

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to use the spread operator when invoking the `newInstance()` method. And the signature of `createEntity()` is wrong. I would recommend define it like that.

```
private fun <T> createEntity(constructor: Constructor<T>, vararg args: Any) : T {
    return constructor.newInstance(*args)
}
```

Comment: Perfect ! In order to return a `T` I had to cast  the return statement though